# Trying to understand reversing a string in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char userInput[256];
    printf("Please enter string to be reversed: ");
    scanf("%s", userInput);
    
    int length = strlen(userInput);
    
    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", userInput[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hi Everyone, I am trying to understand a part of this particular code to reverse a string in C (I understand there are more efficient ways to do so).

For the for loop, why must it be i>= 0 instead of i = 0? Just trying to understand this part TIA

Comment: The condition must be true for the loop body to execute.  If you used `i = 0`, you'd be assigning `0` to `i`, and that's false, so the body of the loop would never execute.  Even if you wrote `i == 0`, the body of the loop would only execute if the input string is empty.  (You should check that `scanf()` returns `1`; if it doesn't, there's a problem.)

Comment: Looping `while (length--) putchar (userInput[length]);` is another way to loop `length` times with the index being `(length-1) >= index >= 0` to output the string in reverse. Also note it should be `size_t length = strlen (userInput);` (`strlen()` returns `size_t`) Don't forget to output a final newline at the end of your program (e.g. `putchar ('\n');`) so your program is POSIX compliant (and doesn't screw up the next prompt in the user's shell)

Answer (score 3):

> For the for loop, why must it be i>= 0 instead of i = 0?

Because `i = 0` assigns 0 to `i`. The conditional expression for the loop will evaluate to `false` and its block would not be executed.

Aside: Limit and validate user input before operating on it. `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully matched and assigned, check for it.

```
if (scanf("%255s", userInput) != 1) {
     complain ();
}
```

And this code does not reverse the string, it only prints it in reverse order.